# Removing NA from csv data file

Tags: r, csv, import, read.csv

I am using this codes to import data

```
counts<-read.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)
```

## [link to view the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u8P8.png)

and to remove NAs from data I am using 2 methods

## 1

```
lists <- lapply(as.list(counts), function(x) x[x != ""])
```

## 2

```
removeEMPTYstrings <- function(x) {
 newVectorWOstrings <- x[x != ""]
 return(newVectorWOstrings)
}

lists <- lapply(as.list(counts), removeEMPTYstrings)
```

but both of these ways are not removing NAs from the data and I am still getting this message "Error: NAs in dataset".

I just want to remove/ignore/unread the NAs in the data and not to remove entire column or row.

Thank you.

Comment: better to use inline reproducible code for the data, rather than add screenshots

Comment: The methods you showed are to remove the blanks and not NA. You may need `is.na`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.omit` to remove the NA

```
counts1 <- na.omit(counts)
```

Or `complete.cases`

```
counts1 <- counts[complete.cases(counts),]
```

---

Or if we need to remove the NA by each column

```
lapply(counts, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Comment: na.omit is also not removing the NAs. I want to keep the incomplete cases.

Comment: @StatBio Please check the `str(counts)`.  Is it real NAs?

Comment: $ Col1     : int [1:125] 2 NA 4 NA NA 7 NA NA NA 11 ...
 $ Col2    : int [1:125] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 11 ...
 $ Col3: int [1:125] NA 3 NA 5 6 NA 8 NA NA 11 ...
 $ Col4: int [1:125] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 9 10 NA

Comment: @StatBio What is the expected output based on it.  Perhaps `lapply(counts, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`, but it depends on the number of NA in each columns, so the lengths will be different

Comment: lapply with function(x), should remove the NAs but still keep the "NA position" empty with no value.

Comment: @StatBio It is removing the value with `!is.na`

Comment: Thank You very much @akurn. The problem seems to be solved. It is working now.